# How to do Paging(ListView)

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing a blog website, what i want is when a certain post that the user post a new pagelist will be available im using ListView how can i do it? can someone give me a tutorial or tell me how to do it?

Comment: simple google search would brings you load of example!!! this is one of them **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142326/Effective-paging-with-List-View-control-in-ASP-NET**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [DataPager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295263%28v=expression.30%29.aspx) control

*To enable users to page through data in either a ListView control or a control that

    implements the IPageableItemContainer interface,you can use a DataPager control. 
    The  DataPager control can be inside the LayoutTemplate template or on the page outside 
    the ListView control. If the DataPager control is not in the ListView control, you must

    set the PagedControlID property to the ID of the ListView control.*